# C# parse string into object

Tags: c#, .net

For the following text:

```
Item 1:
student-pay
history 320.00
math 500.10 extra

Item 2:
history 220.00
math 200.10
```

I would like to parse this text into an Item class. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

I have the following:

```
            var result = input.Split(
                new[] { "item", "Item" }, 
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            foreach (string item in result)
            {
                var lineItems = item.Split(
                    new[] { Environment.NewLine }, 
                    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                foreach (var lineItem in lineItems.Skip(1)) // remove ":"
                {
                        // split line again
// check if numeric
                }
            }

public class Course
{
    public bool StudentPay { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CourseItem> JobItems { get; set; }
}

public class CourseItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public decimal Cost { get; set; }

    public bool Extra { get; set; }
}
```

I want to end up with `List<Items>`

Comment: You should probably show your Item class in your question. And while you're at it, might as well remove all that extra whitespace from your code that makes it difficult to read.

Comment: `Split` is not the best way to parse a string, especially as the substring "item" could appear elsewhere in the input.

Comment: what is your question about? How to fill List? How to create new Item and fill with lineItem? What is best way to keep objects in readable mode and deserialize them?

Comment: `Is there a more efficient way to do this?` Your input isn't any common, serializable structure (xml, json).  So you can make the code as pretty as you want, but you're going to be parsing it yourself in the end.

Comment: I would actually recommend serialising your items. You can even put them in an array and serialize the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that data format your stuck with having to hand code a one off solution.

A much better approach is to use a json format.  Get Newtonsoft.json.  It's a one liner to serialize it and a one liner to deserializer. Add another line for File.Write and File.Read and away you go.

Use JsonConvert.Serialize and JsonConvert.Deserialize, will work most classes (unlike xmlserializer).

Answer (score -1):

Json is probably a better solution but it require having the control of the input string being formatted to json format.

If you have to use your existing string as input, I suggest you to use RegEx to parse each line for the object creation. Regex is the old-fashion way to tackle your problem.